# .NET Fetch all exception in 3rd party app

Tags: c#, .net, exception

We are integrating with a 3rd party application by supplying a file they can import. The file contains many properties(+100) , not all of them are mandatory, we only need a few. However, the application keeps crashing(gently, with an alert due to big try catch) with 'object not set to a reference ...' without a stacktrace. So at some place the 3rd party app is not verifying some optional parameters on nulls causing the crash. Searching what property is searching for a needle in a haystack.

Is it possible somehow to monitor all exceptions of an application we don't have the source of even if they are caught? This so we can get the stacktrace and check with Ilspy what property is causing the problem.

The 3rd party app is from a relatively big company. We cannot just communicate with their developers.

Comment: `We can not just communicate with their developers.`  That's so sad.  But as a developer myself.... Yay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
Assembly otherAssembly = typeof(/* a class of the other assembly */).Assembly;

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, fceea) =>
{
    AppDomain domain = (AppDomain)sender;

    var method = fceea.Exception.TargetSite;
    var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;
    var assembly = declaringType.Assembly;

    if (assembly == otherAssembly)
    {
        // Log the stacktrace of the Exception, or whatever 
        // you want
    }
};
```

This will let you see all the `Exception`s (even those catched). You have to put this code where the program starts (or even in other places it is ok, but try to not execute it multiple times, because the event is AppDomain-wide)

Note that considering how the stack trace inside an exception is handled, perhaps it's better to:

```
if (assembly == otherAssembly)
{
    // Log the stacktrace st of the Exception, or whatever 
    // you want
    string st = new StackTrace(1, true).ToString();
}
```

so that you can see the full stack trace.

Now, as I've suggested you, you could write a small Console app/Winforms app, `Add Reference` to the other exe (yes, you can add as a reference another .exe if that is written in .NET :-) ), and in your `Main` do something like:

```
var otherAssembly = typeof(/* Some type from the other assembly */).Assembly;

// We look all the classes in an assembly for a static Main() that has
// the "right" signature
var main = (from x in otherAssembly.GetTypes()
            from y in x.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            where y.Name == "Main" && (y.ReturnType == typeof(int) || y.ReturnType == typeof(void)) && y.GetGenericArguments().Length == 0
            let parameters = y.GetParameters()
            where parameters.Length == 0 || (parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(string[]))
            select y).Single();

if (main.GetParameters().Length == 0)
{
    // static Main()
    main.Invoke(null, null);
}
else
{
    // static Main(string[] args)

    // Note that new string[0] is the string[] args!
    // You can pass *your* string[] args :-)
    // Or build one however you want
    main.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[0] });
}
```

to invoke the other `Main()`. Clearly before doing this, you have to setup the `FirstChanceException` handler

Comment: Any suggestions how to inject this code? Can you force loading & executing a method in a dll through the config ?

Comment: @MichaelD You put that method in the `Main(...)` of your app. As I've said, it's AppDomain wide.

Comment: We are not referencing the application. It's a standalone application that imports a file we feed it

Comment: @MichaelD You can probably write a console app/winforms app (depending on the type of the other app), add a reference to the exe of the other app (Add Reference, yes you can reference exe files) and "run" the `Main` of the other app manually (`Program.Main()`... perhaps you'll have to use reflection to do it) from your main. Then put your app in the same folder of the other app and launch your program.